# I can't see the three vertical dots in my emulator action bar on Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-actionbar

Hi everyone so I'm kind of new to all of this, and my instructor has some extra code inside of the home class as well as three vertical dots inside of the action bar. He is doing stuff with it and I am not able to catch up because all I have in the action bar is the name of my project. Any help would be appreciated. Here is my code:

```
package com.example.gamee.taskit;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_task_list);


    mItems[0] = new Task();
    mItems[0].setName("Task 1");
    mItems[0].setUpdatedDate("NULL");
    mItems[1] = new Task();
    mItems[1].setName("Task 2");
    mItems[1].setUpdatedDate("NULL");
    mItems[2] = new Task();
    mItems[2].setName("Task 3");
    mItems[2].setUpdatedDate("NULL");
    mItems[3] = new Task();
    mItems[3].setName("Task 4");
    mItems[3].setUpdatedDate("NULL");
    for (Task items : mItems) {
        items.setDate(new Date());
    }
    mAdapter = new TaskAdapter(mItems);

    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    list.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            mTaskLocation = position;
            Task task = mItems[position];
            task.setPosition(position);
            Intent i = new Intent(TaskListActivity.this, SetTaskActivity.class);
            i.putExtra(EXTRA, task);
            startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_CODE);

        }


    });


}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    mUpdatedTask = (Task) data.getSerializableExtra(SetTaskActivity.EXTRA2);
    mItems[mTaskLocation] = mUpdatedTask;
    Task task = new Task();
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


}

private class TaskAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Task> {
    TaskAdapter(Task[] tasks) {
        super(TaskListActivity.this, R.layout.tak_list_row, R.id.view, tasks);

    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        convertView = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        TextView dateView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dateView);
        Task task = getItem(position);
        if (task.getUpdatedDate().equals("NULL")) {
            dateView.setText("No Date Selected");
        } else {
            dateView.setText(task.getUpdatedDate());
            SetTaskActivity.sChecker = false;
        }

        CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkitycheck);
        checkBox.setChecked(task.isDone());
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

}

Also here is my Android manifest. Not exactly sure what an Android manifest is to be honest, but when I looked at an error it mentioned it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".TaskListActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".SetTaskActivity">
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Ok I fixed it, I went to C:\Users\*userName*\AndroidStudioProjects\*project*\app\src\main\res          in files. Then I went to an older project that was made before all of these recent updates that still had the vertical dots, and I went to this same directory. It turns out, it had an extra file called menu. If i copied that into my current project, I was able to copy and past the OnCreateOptionsMenu and OnOptionsItemSelected code blocks without error (after importing Menu and Menu Item of course). Then, I ran it and everything works!